# Pyinstaller and qpageview

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have a PyQt5 project where I am using [qpageview](https://qpageview.org/index.html). I am working on Ubuntu Linux and I am trying to run PyInstaller to make a single executable file, for convenience for me. The application works fine if I run it from a virtual environment, or with all of the Python modules installed locally to my machine (no virtual environment). It has a problem, however, if I run the executable produced by the command `pyinstaller -F src/main.py`, the executable `dist/main`, it runs without any errors, but the actual Page View is just blank, as though there is no PDF.

I have made an simple example application that experiences this phenomenon here (my actual app is much larger than this and has multiple files):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import qpageview

app = QApplication([])

v = qpageview.View()
v.resize(900, 500)
v.show()

v.loadPdf("pyqt.pdf")

app.exec()
```

This assumes there is a PDF at the current working directory called "pyqt5.pdf". Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qpageview depends on python-poppler-qt5, but you have to install it manually. In order to make pyinstaller use python-poppler-qt5 properly, you can add an `import popplerqt5` at the top of your main.py file (or any Python file in your project I would imagine). When you do this, however, it seems you also have to add the option `--hidden-import PyQt5.QtXml` to pyinstaller.

There might be a better way to do this, however.